# Difference between integer and string value for rolling window in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I used the values 360D and 360 (which I thought they were equivalent) for the parameter `window` of the method `.rolling()`. However, they produced different graph. Could you please explain what the difference between those two values was?

```
rolling_stats = data.Ozone.rolling(window='360D').agg(['mean', 'std'])
stats = data.join(rolling_stats)
stats.plot(subplots=True)
plt.show()

rolling_stats = data.Ozone.rolling(window=360).agg(['mean', 'std'])
stats = data.join(rolling_stats)
stats.plot(subplots=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: From the docs: Contrasting to an integer rolling window, this will roll a variable length window corresponding to the time period (time offset).  Each window will be a variable sized based on the observations included in the time-period, This is only valid for datetimelike indexes.

Comment: `360` is window of 360 *records* and `360D` is a _time_ window of 360 _days_

Comment: Oh, I failed to think of that subtlety! Without your succinct explanation, there's no way I could understand the help text ```window : int, or offset
    Size of the moving window. This is the number of observations used for
    calculating the statistic. Each window will be a fixed size.

    If its an offset then this will be the time period of each window. Each
    window will be a variable sized based on the observations included in
    the time-period. This is only valid for datetimelike indexes. This is
    new in 0.19.0``` Thanks, @EdwardKhachatryan.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that when you use the string '360D' it calculates rolling by considering "Calendar Days" while when you use 360 (int) it calculates rolling for business days.

The other diffence is that when using string ('360D') pandas calculates Rolling from the begining of the 'Calendar Year' but when you use integer (360), pandas calculates from the last 360 business days. This is why there is a gap in your second plot, because for the first 359 days, rolling.agg() returns NaN values. However, in the first plot there is no gap. If you look further in details, you will find out that for the first method, the data.Ozone.rolling.agg() is equal to data.Ozone.iloc[0]